# Limit field's pick list options on screen component in a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, picklist, record-type, screen-flow

I am creating a flow to Submit a form in HR for processing and it has 14 required fields and 8 of those are picklists.

One picklist has to only show 4 out of many options due to Record type restrictions.

That works on the actual form, but if a user does not populate the picklist value, I have a screen component on the flow to request the required fields to be populated on that actual screen.

**When I create a Pick List component with pick list resource from the Fields it shows all options of the field, instead of the limited option per Record type (as it is on the form).**

Any ideas? Formula? Thanks

[image: Desired limited options on pick][image: Screen component variable for pick list for Field "Subcategory"]

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience and verified by other posts around the internet (https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lObxQAE) I don't think what you want is directly possible.

The reason is, in a flow, you are not binding the Picklist directly to a record in the same way you do when creating Visualforce pages or components. The screen component doesn't know what record you are modifying as such it doesn't know what record type you care about.

That being said, if you store the record type Id or name in a variable, you can conditionally render a picklist based on this value. So you could create 1 picklist per record type and only show the picklist with the correct values using the conditional rendering properties of the components.

**Disclaimer** While Im positive this will work, I have never done it so I don't have the step by step instructions on hand. You will have to give it a shot yourself and it may end up requiring multiple screens to accomplish depending on your use case.

Its worth noting that conditional rendering of components is only supported in the lightning run time.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I thought that it would be possible to create a screen component with a variable to show only the Pick list options that I want as I will manually put them in the formula without the screen component using logic to select based on record type...but then the screen component has to be linked to the field pick list in order to update the record properly.... I will have to further play with this and figure out your idea! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Assign Record type to that flow, you will achieve it.

first, create a record variable

second, get all record types from the object

third, assign that required record type id and developer name to record variable

then you create your Screen.......